# Gnome shell Window auto-focus not working for specific applications

Tags: fedora, gnome, gnome-shell, gsettings, mutter

I am using fedora 37 with `kernel version 6.2.9`.
Some of the applications like `gnome-terminal` and `gnome software store` when launched from the `Dash` in `gnome-shell` are not focused i.e. they are not being `auto-focused`.
But when they are launched from other way like by gnome search they are working as expected and being `auto-focused`.

Other applications are working fine even if they are launched from the `Dash`.
Another thing is that when some other application is opened for example `Firefox` or `nautilus` then launching `gnome-terminal` or  `gnome software store` works as expected and are `auto-focused`.
I tried setting `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences focus-new-windows 'smart'`, but it makes no difference.

This problem started showing after the last update which includes updating the kernel from `6.1.18` to `6.2.9`, updating `mutter` and `nvidia` driver update.

**UPDATE**
I installed `console` application which is also a terminal emulator by gnome project. It is also showing the same issue as `gnome-terminal` and  `gnome software store`.
I think the applications which use the shell directly or in background, are showing this kind of issues.

Comment: I see this as well but do not know where to report the bug

Comment: I see the same issue.  The first gnome-terminal launched in a session always gets forcused.  But another instance launched with `Ctrl`+`Enter` doesn't.